# Supertokens: Adding custom form fields with modifier function capabilities

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm adding custom fields to the Sign Up form in Supertokens. I see there is a builtin `validate` function and you can basically have a true or false return on some conditional. I was wondering if there was a way to apply a "mask" to a phone number field which forces a format ie: `(123)456-7890` something like an "onBlur()" or "onKeydown()" type of event. Here's my frontendConfig() code. (Snipped for brevity):

````
function inputMask(value) {
  console.log("value: ", value);
  const _num = value.replace(/\D/g, "").match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
  const phoneNumber = `(${_num[1]})${_num[2]}-${_num[3]}`;
  return phoneNumber;
}

EmailPasswordReact.init({
        signInAndUpFeature: {
          signUpForm: {
            formFields: [
              {
                id: "firstname",
                label: "First Name",
                placeholder: "Jane",
              },
              {
                id: "lastname",
                label: "Last Name",
                placeholder: "Doe",
              },
              {
                id: "phone",
                label: "Phone",
                placeholder: "(123)456-7890",
                // as an example
                validate: (value) => {
                  return inputMask(value);
                },
              },
            ],
          },
        },```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `validate` function is only meant for checking if the input is correct or not. It's not meant for normalisation.

The SuperTokens react library render react components for the login / sign up UI, so you can use plain JS to change the form behaviour:

- You want to add an event listener on the custom input field which fires on the `blur` event. In order to add this, you need to find that input field using JS and call `addEventListener` on it - this should be done in the `useEffect` block of the page that shows the sign up form.
- When the event is fired, you want to call the `inputMask` function and change the value of the form field to be equal to that function's output.
- You should also implement logic in the `validate` function to check that the user's input (normalised or not) is correct.
- Finally, in case the input field blur event doesn't happen, then you want to normalise the user's input when the sign up button is clicked as well. This can be achieved via the [override feature](https://supertokens.com/docs/emailpassword/advanced-customizations/frontend-functions-override/usage).

First, in order to add the event listener, you want [override the react component in the sign up](https://supertokens.com/docs/emailpassword/advanced-customizations/react-component-override/usage) form and use a `useEffect` hook in your custom component. The component to override is called `EmailPasswordSignUpForm_Override` (supertokens-auth-react SDK version >= 0.20.0)

```js
EmailPasswordReact.init({
  override: {
    components: {
      EmailPasswordSignUpForm_Override: ({ DefaultComponent, ...props }) => {
        React.useEffect(() => {
          // This will get fired each time the sign up form is shown to the user
          // TODO: adding the event listener logic come in here...
        }, [])
        return <DefaultComponent {...props} />;
      }
    }
  },
  signInAndUpFeature: {...}
})
```

Then you want to find the input field representing the input for the phone number. You can find it like:

```js
React.useEffect(() => {
  // Note that the phone number input is the 5th element in the sign up form. That's why we do nth-child(5)
  let input = document.querySelector("#supertokens-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("form > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > div > input");

  function onBlur() {
    let phoneNumber = input.value;
    let normalisedPhoneNumber = inputMask(phoneNumber);
    input.value = normalisedPhoneNumber;
  }

  input.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
  return () => {
    input.removeEventListener('blur', onBlur);
  }
}, [])
```

The above will noramlise the phone number when the phone number input is blurred. Whilst the above works from a UI point of view, when the sign up button is clicked, or when the `validate` function is called, the user's input may still be unnormalised (cause the react state in the library has not been updated). So you should also call the `inputMask` function during the `validate` function call and when `signUp` is clicked:

#### Normalise when `signUp` is clicked

```js
EmailPasswordReact.init({
  override: {
    functions: (oI) => {
      return {
        ...oI,
        signUp: async function (input) {
          // we normalise the phone input
          input.formFields = input.formFields.map(f => {
            if (f.id === "phone") {
              return {
                ...f,
                value: inputMask(f.value)
              }
            }
            return f;
          })

          // we call the original implementation
          return oI.signUp(input);
        }
      }
    }
  }
})
```

#### Normalise when `validate` function is called:

```js
validate: (value) => {
  value = inputMask(value);
  // TODO: logic for checking input syntax. If there is an error, return a string else undefined
}
```

So the overall code looks like:

```js
import React from 'react'
import EmailPasswordReact from 'supertokens-auth-react/recipe/emailpassword'
import SessionReact from 'supertokens-auth-react/recipe/session'
import { appInfo } from './appInfo'

export let frontendConfig = () => {
  return {
    appInfo,
    recipeList: [
      EmailPasswordReact.init({
        override: {
          functions: (oI) => {
            return {
              ...oI,
              signUp: async function (input) {
                // we normalise the phone input
                input.formFields = input.formFields.map(f => {
                  if (f.id === "phone") {
                    return {
                      ...f,
                      value: inputMask(f.value)
                    }
                  }
                  return f;
                })

                // we call the original implementation
                return oI.signUp(input);
              }
            }
          },
          components: {
            EmailPasswordSignUpForm_Override: ({ DefaultComponent, ...props }) => {
              React.useEffect(() => {
                let input = document.querySelector("#supertokens-root").shadowRoot.querySelector("form > div:nth-child(5) > div:nth-child(2) > div > input");

                function onBlur() {
                  let phoneNumber = input.value;
                  let normalisedPhoneNumber = inputMask(phoneNumber);
                  input.value = normalisedPhoneNumber;
                }

                input.addEventListener('blur', onBlur);
                return () => {
                  input.removeEventListener('blur', onBlur);
                }
              }, [])
              return <DefaultComponent {...props} />;
            }
          }
        },
        signInAndUpFeature: {
          signUpForm: {
            formFields: [
              {
                id: "firstname",
                label: "First Name",
                placeholder: "Jane",
              },
              {
                id: "lastname",
                label: "Last Name",
                placeholder: "Doe",
              },
              {
                id: "phone",
                label: "Phone",
                placeholder: "(123)456-7890",
                validate: (value) => {
                  value = inputMask(value);
                  // TODO: logic for checking input syntax
                  return undefined;
                }
              },
            ],
          },
        }
      }),
      SessionReact.init(),
    ],
  }
}

function inputMask(value) {
  const _num = value.replace(/\D/g, "").match(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/);
  const phoneNumber = `(${_num[1]})${_num[2]}-${_num[3]}`;
  return phoneNumber;
}
```

Hope this helps!